# Apache web server LDAP - How to allow a non-ldap user access?

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

Apologies in advance for sounding naive but I am new to this and stuck since days to no good.

I have set up LDAP on apache web server using below link and it is working good.

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html

I am able to login to the application using a valid account in the directory. Now I want to create a non-ldap user (common user for API access) that can be allowed access through the web server? Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise to create `API accounts` in your Active Directory. (in the company I work for, we use that and call them `service accounts`)

Centralizing access is the best practice, if you start mixing authentication methods in your application/website it can quickly become a nightmare of spaghetti code to maintain.

Centralizing access also improves security by allowing you to manage access in a single place.

If you do not want to go this way, you have the possibility to create a secondary authentication method through `local users` that would be stored in a database. 
If you go this way, please do not store passwords in a non-encrypted way. Look for the following functions: [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). When using SQL to transact with your database, make sure you do not end up with [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), it can be disastrous to have `SQL Injection` in your login script.